# Red error Screen before data loads in flutter firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to recieve data from stream builder based on whether a user is searching for another user but I get an error for about 1 second before the data loads. The error says that the 'fieldname' doesn't exists in document snapshot. It exists and loads fine after a second (maybe while searching for field, it shows error and removes it as it finds the field). How can I get rid of that. Thanks in advance.
I use flutter and firebase with null safety.

The code:

```
body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: homePageStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: (snapshot.data as QuerySnapshot).docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var dataSnapshot = snapshot.data as QuerySnapshot;
                  var DocData = dataSnapshot.docs[index];
                
                  return Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10,),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                        color: Colors.black38,),
                      child: isSearching
                          ? Column(
                        children: [
                          Center(
                              child: Text(
                                DocData['Name'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
                              )),
                          Center(
                              child: Text(
                                DocData['Email'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6),
                                    fontSize: 20),
                              ))
                        ],
                      )
                          : Center(
                          child: Text(
                            DocData['Name'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
                          )));
                })
                : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
```

Here is home page Stream which changes on pressing a button

```
if (SearchUserController.text != '') {
                      setState(() {
                        isSearching = true;
                        homePageStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('Users')
                            .where('Name', isEqualTo: SearchUserController.text)
                            .snapshots();
                      });
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        isSearching = false;
                        homePageStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('Users')
                            .doc(userMail)
                            .collection('Chat rooms')
                            .snapshots();
                      });
                    }
```

They are both querysnashots and userMail is a predefined string.

I am sure the field exists and the code does find it after 1 sec of showing error. The error is the problem and I want it to wait for the data instead of showing error.

The error

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following StateError was thrown building:
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findKeyValueInMap (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:86:7)
#1      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findComponent (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:104:41)
#2      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:120:26)
#3      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:92:48)
#4      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.[] (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:96:40)
...
====================================================================================================
```

However i still get the required result.
Also, this happens only once per start. Switching back to last stream or updating it doesn't cause the error(Probably because it is already loaded by the time).
Pls help

Edit: I think the problem is that the value isnt loaded when it shows error. Is there any way to load the document snapshot value while app starts.

Comment: on-screen load it might show a red error screen, if values are null yet before they are fetched from firebase, try to check not null and then use values

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: i Am already using snapshot.hasData. how can i null check for fields

Comment: may be checking null value like this..
(passportNumber != null)
                            ? ProfileListTile(
                                title: "Passport Number",
                                value: "${model.userProfile.passportNumber}",
                                iconColor: Colors.blue,
                                icon: Icons.email,
                              )
                            : Container(),

Comment: Can you please add this as an answer. it is difficult to understand like this

Comment: The problem is not null vaLue of field, but unable to determine existence of field

Answer (score 0):

In itemCount check !null value-

itemCount: snapshot.data != null
? snapshot.data!.docs.length
: 0,

I believe this will solve your issue.

Comment: the same problem has come again. What to do